# How can I get the req.params in the deserializeUser function of passport?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

My serializeUser function looks like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
  console.log("serialize")
  console.log(req.params)
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

My deserializeUser function looks like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (req, id, done) {
  console.log("deserialize")
  console.log(req.params)
  console.log(id)
  // ...... Some other code
});
```

My routes are something like this:

```
/api/:name/list
/api/product/:name
....
```

In the serializeUser function I can get the name param with: req.params.name

In the deserializeUser function is the req.params an empty object {}.

How can I access the req.params.name in the deserializeUser function?

Answer (score 0):

With above code only the `user.id` is serialized in the session. Instead of just serializing the id, you could wrap the id and the params in an object and serialize that:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
  done(null, { id: user.id, params: req.params} );
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (serializedData, done) {     
  console.log(serializedData.params)
  console.log(serializedData.id)
  // ...... Some other code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(res, user, done) {
  let data ={
    id : user.id,
    params: res.params
  }
    done(null, data);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(data, done) {
    let {id , params} = data
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```